# Centering tables in document class apa6

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, apa6

I'm using the `apa6` class in `doc` mode for my thesis.

Now, when I create a table and try to center it on a page, the table is centered alright.
The caption, however, still floats on the left of the page where the table used to be.

This what it looks like:

[image: Table with incorrectly positioned caption]

I would like the caption to align with the left side of the table.

This is basicly what my .tex-file looks like:

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}

\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\shorttitle{Some title}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \center
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{table1}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        Test1 & 1 & 2\\
        Test2 & 1 & 2\\
        Test3 & 1 & 2\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Rather than posting fragments, it's better to post a complete, compilable minimal example. Especially in this case, since the `apa6` class requires `\shorttitle` to be used, so you can't just piece together your fragments.  Also, you should use `\centering` not `\center` inside your tables.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! About the use of the `apa6` document classs: Is this a requirement of your school or is this something you can select yourself? A design choice embedded in the `apa6e` class is that all float captions are typeset left-justified on two lines, with a line break between "Tabelle x" (in German because of your babel setting) and the actual text of the caption. In addition, the tabular materials should also be set left-justified, i.e., you shouldn't use the `\centering` command. If you don't like these design choices, a different document class may be better suited to your needs.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the comment. I fixed my example and added a screenshot to clarify the problem.

Comment: Hi Mico, I use apa6 because besides from the tables it works smoothly and does everything I need. I edited my question because it appears it was unclar. I want the captions to be left justified. It is their position relative to the table that is off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package is loaded by the `apa6` class, so you can use its commands to set the caption formatting.  Adding:

```
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
```

will cause the caption to be centred. However, this doesn't seem to be the exact formatting you want.  What you want a left aligned caption aligned to the natural width of the table.  As Axel Sommerfeldt notes in the comments, there is an command in the `caption` package which allows you to place a table and its caption in a box.  This will allow you to do what you want quite simply.  The command has not yet made it into the documentation of `caption` (v3.2).

The syntax of this command is:

```
\captionbox[⟨list entry⟩]{⟨heading⟩}[⟨width⟩][⟨inner-pos⟩]{⟨contents⟩}
\captionbox*{⟨heading⟩}[⟨width⟩][⟨inner-pos⟩]{⟨contents⟩}
```

(quoting from the `subcaption` package by the same author:)

> The arguments `⟨list entry⟩` & `⟨heading⟩` will be used for
>   typesetting the `\caption`. `⟨width⟩` is the width of the resulting
>   `\parbox`; the default value is the width of the contents.
>
> `⟨inner-pos⟩` specifies how the contents will be justified inside the
>   resulting `\parbox`; it can be either `c` (for `\centering`), `l` (for
>   `\raggedright`), `r` (for `\raggedleft`), or `s` (for no special
>   justification). The default is `c`. (But you can use any justification
>   defined with `\DeclareCaptionJustification` as well, e.g.
>   `centerlast`.)

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}

\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\shorttitle{A title}
\begin{document}
Example of a table:

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \captionbox{Some caption\label{table1}}{%
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        Test1 & 1 & 2\\
        Test2 & 1 & 2\\
        Test3 & 1 & 2\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unless you have very strict formatting requirements, I would simply stick to centred captions instead of doing this.

(Thanks to both Werner and Axel for their comments on this answer.)

Comment: Actually, [`apa6`](http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6) already loads [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and sets `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}`. So, you only need to use `\captionsetup{justification=centering}`.

Comment: Thanks, Alan. I have edited my question because it seems it was unclear. Nonetheless, I've tried various options of the \captionsetup but none of them seems to do the trick.

Comment: @crash I've updated my answer.  Seems like a lot of work.  You might want to check out the other answers to the question I linked to.

Comment: Instead of `\setuptable` one could use `\captionbox{<caption>}{<table>}`. Unfortunately this command isn't documented yet, but it's avail since `caption` v3.2 and have the same syntax as `\subcaptionbox` documented in the `subcaption` package documentation.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thanks for the comment. I've updated my answer to use that instead.  I just quoted the explanation of the syntax directly from the `subcaption` package docs; if there's any difference between the two, feel free to edit.

Comment: @AlanMunn The only difference is that `\subcaptionbox` typesets a sub-caption while `\captionbox` typesets a regular one, so your answer is fine. But maybe one should change "undocumented" to "not-yet-documented" because "undocumented" could yield to the wrong impression it's better to not using this command. But it's definitely ok to use it, the only reason why it's not documented yet is that I've a full-time job, a wife, and cats ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can load the [`zref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) with the `savepos` module. This allows you to use `\zsavepos{<label>}` that saves the (x,y) coordinates of `<label>` on the page, retrievable via `\zposx{<label>}` and `\zposy{<label>}` in `s`caled `p`oints (or `sp`). This requires at least two compiles.

[image: Caption sized to width of table via zref's \zsavepos]

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}% http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6

%\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
%\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}% http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref

\shorttitle{Some title}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\zposx{tabR}sp-\zposx{tabL}sp\relax}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{table1}
    \zsavepos{tabL}\begin{tabular}{lcc}% Save tabular LEFT coordinate
        \toprule
        Test1 & 1 & 2\\
        Test2 & 1 & 2\\
        Test3 & 1 & 2\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\zsavepos{tabR}% Save tabular RIGHT coordinate
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You place a label to the left of your `tabular` environment (say `tabL`), and one to the right (say `tabR`). Then, `\dimexpr\zposx{tabR}sp-\zposy{tabL}sp\relax` gives the exact horizontal distance between `tabL` and `tabR`, which you use as the length restriction to a `minipage`.

You would need a different label for each `tabular` you want to force this way. It would be possible to automate this procedure by defining your own environment (say) `mytable` and `mytabular`, which you would use instead of `table`.