# Center a table's caption using apa6 with man mode

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, apa6

There are several questions that are related, yet not quite the answer to this question:

1. [Centering tables in document class apa6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42209/centering-tables-in-document-class-apa6)
2. [How do force center-alignment in a caption in a figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60344/how-do-force-center-alignment-in-a-caption-in-a-figure)

The questions are only relevant when the `apa6` document is in the `doc` mode.

This post is seeking advice on using centered caption in `man` mode.

For example, in `doc` mode, everything works fine:

```
\documentclass[apacite,noextraspace]{apa6} 

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amscd} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=on,justification=centering}
\shorttitle{test}
\geometry{left=1.in,right=1.in,top=1.in,bottom=1.in} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\caption{Matrix of Questions} 
\label{tab:one}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Header }\\
  \cline{2-4}
 Left Column & $\phi$ & $\rho$ & $\theta$ \\ 
  \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Good centered caption]

However, the same code but in `man` mode, added only `man` to documentclass, the results are poor:

```
\documentclass[man,apacite,noextraspace]{apa6} 

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amscd} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=on,justification=centering}
\shorttitle{test}
\geometry{left=1.in,right=1.in,top=1.in,bottom=1.in} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\caption{Matrix of Questions} 
\label{tab:one}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Header }\\
  \cline{2-4}
 Left Column & $\phi$ & $\rho$ & $\theta$ \\ 
  \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Bad Left Table Caption]

Is there a way to change this?

If not, is there a way to align the table label (e.g. "Table 1") to the left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need the following line in your preamble

```
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{tabletext}{\hspace{-\parindent}\textit{#1}}
```

This is the same definition used for `doc` mode.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[man,apacite,noextraspace]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}

\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{tabletext}{\hspace{-\parindent}\textit{#1}}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=on,justification=centering}

\shorttitle{test}
\geometry{left=1.in,right=1.in,top=1.in,bottom=1.in}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Matrix of Questions}
\label{tab:one}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Header }\\
  \cline{2-4}
 Left Column & $\phi$ & $\rho$ & $\theta$ \\
  \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]